# Newest questions with YOUR TAGS only

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Not sure if this should be here or meta.SO, but...

A really handy feature for me, and I assume others, would be the option to see **ONLY** questions tagged with your tags, but in chronological order.

Comment: @Dori - Thanks for the heads up.  That is pretty disappointing, though.

Answer (score 4):

As Jeff mentioned [in his post:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags/101575#101575)

> There is a default tag filter on http://stackexchange.com/ but you
>   must be logged in:
>
> 1. Click on Filtered Questions
> 2. Click on "Favourite tags
>
> Then look for the default "Favorite Tags" filter.
>
> [image]
>
> You can browse it in your browser, or have it emailed to you, or get
>   the RSS feed at the bottom of the page (also present in the headers,
>   too, if your browser auto-detects).
>
> [image: favorite tags RSS feed]