# Filter out unanswered question with a particular tag

Tags: support

It might look like a duplicate question with [Is there any way to see all the questions that are tagged with my favorite tags?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4674/is-there-any-way-to-see-all-the-questions-that-are-tagged-with-my-favorite-tags/4675), but it is not.
What I'm looking for is a **search syntax** to filter out unanswered questions with a particular tag.
I also found a post which shows how one can create filtered questions on [stackexchange](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1485/newest-questions-with-your-tags-only/4971#4971) - but I would want to achieve the same functionality from being with SuperUser.

Note: When I refer to search syntax I'm expecting something similar to what google offer like `allinurl` or `allintitle` etc.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean, you want to see them, or you don't want to see them?

If you want to see them,  you can enter a search term like

```
[windows-7] answers:0
```

You can see all of the options by going to [a search page](https://superuser.com/search?q=[windows-7]%20answers%3A0) and clicking on the `Advanced Search Tips` button, or going to the [search help page](https://superuser.com/help/searching).

Comment: search help page link was very helpful. Many Thanks!